# How do I parse this javascript from Oddshark.com with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Working on a little web scraping program to get some data and help me make some bets.

Ultimately, I want to parse the "Trends" section under each game of the current week on pages like this (https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/arizona-kansas-city-odds-november-11-2018-971332)

My current algorithm:

1. GET https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/scores
2. Parse the webpage for the little "vs" button which holds links to all the games
3. Parse for the Trends

Here's how I started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/scores"
result = requests.get("https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/scores")
print ("Status: ", result.status_code)

content = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

print (soup)
```

When I look at the output, I don't really see any of those links. Is it cause a lot of the site of javascript?

Any pointers on the code/algorithm appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the internal API this sites uses to get all the links & iterate over these to get the trends info which is embedded in a `script` tag with `id:gc-data` :

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    'https://io.oddsshark.com/ticker/nfl', 
    headers = {
        'referer': 'https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/scores'
    }
)

links = [
    (
        t["event_date"], 
        t["away_name"], 
        t["home_name"], 
        "https://www.oddsshark.com{}".format(t["matchup_link"])
    )
    for t in r.json()['matchups']
    if t["type"] == "matchup"
]

for t in links:
    print("{} - {} vs {} => {}".format(t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3]))
    r = requests.get(t[3])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    trends = [
        json.loads(v.text)
        for v in soup.findAll('script', {"type":"application/json", "id":"gc-data"})
    ]
    print(trends[0]["oddsshark_gamecenter"]["trends"])
    print("#########################################")
```

Comment: wow that's awesome. I started using Google's Puppeteer because i read it would be more appropriate for what I wanted to do.

How did you know about the api oddshark uses? Is that what the https://io.oddsshark.com/ticker/nfl url is? Cause if i try to go to that webpage, it says unauthorized

Comment: @user1224478 if you check the network tab you will see that this url is called. It seems it needs the referer header to get through the unauthorized message `curl "https://io.oddsshark.com/ticker/nfl" -H "referer: https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/scores"`

Comment: do you mind explaining what exactly I should be looking for? I am on Chrome looking at the Network tab but there's a lot of stuff going on. Should I see what you mentioned as I click on the link to the matchup page?

Comment: try filtering XHR in chrome dev console

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see those links is that they're not in the response that `requests` receives.  This is very likely for one of two reasons:

1. The server recognizes that you are trying to scrape the site with a script, and sends you different content.  Usually this is because of the `User-Agent` set by `requests`.
2. The content is added dynamically via JavaScript that runs in the browser.

You could probably render this content using a headless browser in your python script and end up with the same content you see when you visit the site with Chrome et.  Per (1) it might be necessary to experiment with the `User-Agent` header in your request also.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded via javascript to the trends table, but is actually included in a `script` tag inside the html that you receive. You can parse it like this:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0'
}

response = requests.get('https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/arizona-kansas-city-odds-november-11-2018-971332', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

data = json.loads(soup.find("script", {'id': 'gc-data'}).text)
print(data['oddsshark_gamecenter']['trends'])
```

Outputs:

> {'local': {'title': 'Trends'}, 'away': [{'value': 'Arizona is 4-1-1
>   ATS in its last 6 games '}, {'value': 'Arizona is 2-6 SU in its last 8
>   games '}, {'value': "The total has gone UNDER in 8 of Arizona's last
>   12 games "}, {'value': 'Arizona is 3-7-1 ATS in its last 11 games on
>   the road'}, {'value': 'Arizona is 2-4 SU in its last 6 games on the
>   road'}...

Comment: This script tag is found on the matchup page url itself correct? Not from the scores page